# How to get product configrable id in cart in magento 2 using jquery

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, jquery, phtml

> i have a custom module for shipping methods in magento 2
>
> i need to **get config product id** in the cart list using jquery

Date-block.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(
    ['jquery','jquery/ui'],
    //function($) {
      $(document).ready( function() {
        //alert(1);
        // read checkoutconfig
        var quoteData = checkoutConfig.quoteItemData,
          quote_length = quoteData.length,
          prep_times = [],
          creation_dates = [],
          cake_names = [],
          item_ids = [];

        // Manually prepare this list either by cake name or by item id


        var cakes_prep_time_by_name = {
'1101':'4',}
for(var i = 0; i < quote_length; i++) {
           // quoteData[i].name
           //var prep_time = quoteData[i].prep_time; //assumed
           //prep_times.push(prep_time);

           var order_time = quoteData[i].created_at;
           creation_dates.push(order_time);

           var cake_name = quoteData[i].name;
           cake_names.push(cake_name);

           var item_id = quoteData[i].item_id;
           item_ids.push(item_id);

           var prep_time = cakes_prep_time_by_name[cake_name];
           console.log(cake_name+'/'+prep_time);
           prep_times.push(prep_time);
</script>
```

when i go to check out i need to get all configurable products ids and new custom attribute

any one have idea???

Comment: share your code where you want this config mean configurable product id ?

Comment: Added code........................

Comment: I would suggest to use window.checkoutConfig functionality. I am not sure what you exactly wanted by you may refer this link. https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-more-variable-to-window-checkoutconfig/

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
alert(quoteData[i].product_id);
```

I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: how i can get custom product attribute value in magento 2

Comment: Can you please give me your url ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a tamper monkey script, and feel this might help you compile what you need or extend the logic, to get the product id from a given shopping cart item within the checkout using jQuery and knockout in tandem.

```javascript
// Load the contexts when needed
let jQuery = require('jquery');
let ko = require('knockout');

// use jQuery to get all the items in the shopping cart. 
// Change the selector if your checkout plugin uses different stylings.
jQuery('.checkout-product__name-qty').each((i,e) => 
{
    // Get the knockout context for the given checkout element.
    let context = ko.contextFor(e);

    // The actual quote item data is in the parent of the selected element that I chose to target.
    let quote_item_id = ko.contextFor(e).$parent.item_id;

    // Get the checkoutConfig quote item data
    let quote_data = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;

    // Filter out our quote item
    let quote_item = quote_data.filter((item) => {return parseInt(item.item_id) === quote_item_id}).pop();
    
    // get the product ID from the quote item.
    let product_id = quote_item.product.entity_id;
});
```